# Get Geometry of Inserted Point

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, code-review, forms

#### Description

I have a project that must create default values in fields when he is trying to insert a new feature. As shown in the figure beneath.

I'm using PyQGIS 3.28

#### Problem

In the image below, there's an field called `ID_PM`, this field default value is only possible if point is inside polygon layer `ZAPM`

If the point is not inside any polygon it must **close** the attributes form and show an error message to the user.

#### Requirements

- Get geometry of inserted point
- Verify if it's inside polygon layer
- Close attributes form:  if point geom is not inside polygon layer
- Change default field value:  if point geom is inside polygon layer

#### Code

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsDefaultValue

layername = "PM"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]


def fiels_to_text_edit(layer,field,value):
    config =  {'IsMultiline': False, 'UseHtml': False}
    layer.editFormConfig().setWidgetConfig("TextEdit", config)
    default_value = QgsDefaultValue()
    default_value.setExpression(f"'{value}'")
    field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(field)
    
    # Set the default value for the specific field
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(field_index, default_value)


layer_nro = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("NRO")[0]
features = layer_nro.getFeatures()
first_feature = next(features)
ref_nro_value = first_feature["REF_NRO"]
g2r = first_feature["G2R_NRO"]


layer_commune = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("FT_Commune")[0]
features = layer_commune.getFeatures()
first_feature = next(features)
commune = first_feature["NOM"]


fiels_to_text_edit(layer, "REF_NRO",ref_nro_value)
fiels_to_text_edit(layer, "COMMUNE",commune)
fiels_to_text_edit(layer, "G2R",g2r)
```

Any flaw in my code, feel free to correct it.

[image]